# How to generate a line chart with too many data in ruby/ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I'm trying to generate a line chart with data I take from a database.

The data basically have a date field, an estimated progress field and a real progress field.

The progresses may be nil but the date is always there.

Since I don't know what are the intervals of the date and I need the intervals of the date distributed uniformly , I want to make the data from the first date until the last date with steps of 1 day.

For example, let's say I have this in the database:

```
| date        | estimated progress        | real progress        |
| 2012-08-01  | 0.0                       |                      |
| 2012-08-02  |                           | 0.15                 |
| 2012-08-05  | 0.3                       |                      |
```

I would like to generate a line chart with this info:

```
x = [2012-08-01, 2012-08-02, 2012-08-03, 2012-08-04, 2012-08-05]
ep = [0.0 , 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3]
rp = [nil , 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15 ]
```

But since the start date and the finish date can be way too separated, I'd like to show the x labels with a custom interval. It could be every 3, 5 or 7 days depending on the distance between those dates.

I'm trying this with `gchartrb` which use the google chart api but I realized I can't have nil values inside my data. So I should replace it with 0.0 even though it's not 0. It's unknown.

The other problem I found is that I don't know how to specify the labels to show those intervals I said before. It just show me every label and therefore, it's not readable.

I'm looking for another gem, a solution for gchartrb or ideas to generate the data differently and make it understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check this link:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts.

Here is also good library for charts:
[Flotr 2](https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/Flotr2) and gem for it [flotr2-rails](https://github.com/littlebtc/flotr2-rails).

For Flotr 2 it is worth to check [example](http://www.humblesoftware.com/flotr2/#!basic-time) with time/dates labels on axis.

Comment: Well Highcharts is not an option because it's for an enterprise application. It's time to try Flotr2 and I don't see any documentation for flotr2-rails.